# Find original main domain name based on add-on domain name

Tags: dns, hosting, cpanel, add-on

This may not even be possible but I'm trying to figure out the URL of the main domain for an add-on domain.

Lets say for example the site is at `mymaindomain.com.`

If I go to

```
http://mymaindomain.com/cpanel (or :2082 or :2083)
```

I get nothing.

That is because `mymaindomain.com` is an add on domain for the hosting account.

Lets say the primary domain on the account is  `myprimarydomain.com` and this was the domain originally set up with the hosting account.  However, this domain is no longer valid and not being leased by the hosting client anymore.

If I log in to cpanel using the old main domain by going to

`http://myprimarydomain.com/cpanel (or :2082 or :2083)`

I am able to get into cpanel.

The problem is,  there must be a new main domain name associated with this account, but I don't know what it is.

Is there any way to find this out given cpanel access to the account?

Is there any other way to find out what the primary domain is on the account?

Any help is much appreciated and bounty will be awarded promptly to the first correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my rep is too low to comment yet,  I was wondering if you are able to get the IP of your server once you are in cpanel.  (Should be on the right side).   If so ...  can you go here and input the IP and tell me what the 'node hostname' says?  Also ISP might help.

[getIP.com](http://www.getIP.com)

Comment: Yeah I did, I don't want to give out the domain name on here, but its not one I had previously.  So should I just try to go to cpanel on that domain or is there something else I should do.

Comment: Depending on what you needed the domain for, you should be able to get to the cpanel login but your password may not work.

Comment: Well cpanel didn't work but I was able to use my WHM login.   Im suprised this was such a simple solution.   You basically told me how to get the domain though, which is what I was asking for, so I'll award you the bounty.  Thanks for the help!  :)