# jQuery Ajax readystate 0 status 0 in Windows 8 (8.1) on Chrome ONLY

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, windows-8.1, readystate

I have this bit of jQuery doing an ajax call.   The script was having issues in IE and Chrome on Win 8.1 only,   however, i changed a few things (including ommitting a closing php tag that might have been causing issues) and now IE works and on my Win 8.1 on Chrome it works, but the client is still reporting issues.

Can anyone see a problem with my script that would cause this to fail on Win 8.1 on Chrome ONLY?   (BTW, Safari and Opera were probably not tested by client so may also be failing on those).

I have literally read for hours and hours on SO and other question/answer sites,  as well as many different related forums etc.   I have tried many of the different suggestions with no luck.

Obviously, the first thing people think is Cross Domain issue,  which the site is hosted on an "add-on" domain, but I'm calling the script at the same URL.  Should I be calling it using the main domain URL instead? (I can't figure out what that main domain is at the moment, see this question: [Find original main domain name based on add-on domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191329/find-original-main-domain-name-based-on-add-on-domain-name))

Client is getting alerts from the ajax error block:

```
readystate = 0
status = 0
responseText = ''
statusText = 'error'
```

Any help is much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for weeks now.

Here is my jQuery:

```
            $('#bkdl-submit').on('click', function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var tempvar = $('#bkdl-email').val();

                if (IsEmail(tempvar)) {

                    $('#loading-image').show();
                    $('#bkdl-submit').hide();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://addondomain.com/wp-content/themes/html/bkdl-ajax.php?nocache="+Date.now(),
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {
                            email: tempvar
                        },
                        success: function (data) {

                            $("#bkdl-email").css('background-color', '#f00');
                            $("#bkdl-email").val('');
                            $("#hidlink").attr('href', data);
                            $("#hidlink").text('Click to Download');
                            $("#hidlink").show();
                            $("#bkdl-submit").hide();
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $('#loading-image').hide();

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, strError, strHttpStatus) {

                            alert(JSON.stringify(xhr, null, 2));
                            alert(strHttpStatus);
                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    alert('Invalid Email');
                }

                return false;
            });
```

The AJAX PHP script in case that helps...

```
<?php
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!IS_AJAX) {die('Restricted access1');}
$pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],getenv('HTTP_HOST'));
if($pos===false) { die('Restricted access'); }

require_once 'Ctct/autoload.php';
use Ctct\ConstantContact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\Contact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\ContactList;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\EmailAddress;
use Ctct\Exceptions\CtctException;
define("APIKEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);

// check if the form was submitted

if (isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 1) {

    $email =  strip_tags(htmlentities(trim($_POST['email']))); 
    $action = "Getting Contact By Email Address";

    try {
        // check to see if a contact with the email addess already exists in the account
        $response = $cc->getContactByEmail(ACCESS_TOKEN, $email);

        // create a new contact if one does not exist
        if (empty($response->results)) {
                $action = "Creating Contact";
                $contact = new Contact();
                $contact->addEmail($_POST['email']);
                $contact->addList('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
                $contact->first_name = '';
                $contact->last_name = '';
                $returnContact = $cc->addContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact);
        // update the existing contact if address already existed
        } else {
                $action = "Updating Contact";
                $contact = $response->results[0];
                $contact->addList('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
                $contact->first_name = '';
                $contact->last_name = '';
                $returnContact = $cc->updateContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact);
        }

echo 'http://addondomain.com/wp-content/themes/html/giveaway.pdf';

// catch any exceptions thrown and email to dev
} catch (CtctException $ex) {

    $errorvar = print_r($ex->getErrors(), true);
    mail('deverrors@gmail.com', 'test', $errorvar);
    die();
}
} else {
    echo 'Invalid Email'; exit;

}
exit;
```

Comment: `method: "POST",` isn't it should be `type: "POST",`.

Comment: type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.  (I'm using 1.11.1 but I'll try anyway)

Comment: document.domain would refer to the proper one.

Comment: Thanks for the revenge downvote guy.  Real stand up person who goes around downvoting peoples questions without merit.   Get a life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually ended up being the little `?>` at the end of the ajax file.

I know you are supposed to ommit them and I try to remove them whenever I see them at the bottom of a file, but I never knew it could cause issues like this, with ajax calls.

Apparently MS new security policies in win8 had something to do with it.   I'm still not too clear on how that plays into it but I was told that by someone on here.

So yeah... lesson of the day ...

**Do not close your PHP files with a PHP closing tag ?> or you could have issues in win8**